# Attempt to save to stream as PNG I get "Expression has been evaluated and has no value void"

Tags: c#, image, lambda, stream, .net-core

I am trying to create API in .net core 2.0 to convert string to base64 image Qrcode as below. 
I am currently using "ZXing.net" and "CoreCompat.System.Drawing" nugget packages in my project. When I tried to save to stream as PNG
i.e. "bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) I get Expression has been evaluated and has no value  void"

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

```
   ` var ss = "123longstringtoencodedhhhh34444hhh123";
        var qr = new ZXing.BarcodeWriterPixelData
        {
            Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions { Height = 250, Width = 250, Margin = 0 }
        };

        var pixelData = qr.Write(ss);
        using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            try
            {
                // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0,
                    pixelData.Pixels.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }


            // trying to save to stream as PNG

            bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

error
bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) Expression has been evaluated and has no value  void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Two Dependencies are required which can be installed as nuget package from Nuget Package Manager:

- CoreCompat.System.Drawing
- ZXing.Net

I got the error message because I missed this line

- "var pixelData = qr.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(ss));"

  var ss = "123longstringtoencodedhhhh34444hhh123";

See complete code below

```
        var qr = new ZXing.BarcodeWriterPixelData()
        {
            Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions { Height = 250, Width = 250, Margin = 0 }
        };

        var pixelData = qr.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(ss));

        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))


        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }

            bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

           return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        }
    }
```